# How to get the Current Date Automatically (SCALA)

Tags: scala, import

I am trying to make a program that tells you the phase of the moon depending on how many days from the present you are. Is there a way to get the current date without needing to ask the user what the date is? I assume this would need to pull data from a website? Or maybe from the user's machine? I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this problem.

I understand that I could use ReadLine and ask for the date in (MM/DD/YYYY) but I feel that it could be more streamlined if I could have this automatically.

Could anyone point me to the answer or perhaps some resources to learn about how to tackle this issue, I'm not entirely sure where to go, and since I'm new to stackoverflow, this seems like the place to ask.

I see something along the lines of "Calendar", would I have to import something like

```
import Calendar.io._
```

And then could I ask for the specific day?

Comment: `LocalDate.now()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: i use `import org.joda.time.DateTime; DateTime.now.toLocalDate` or `DateTime.now.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")` if you want a String instead.